# using bash, compare two directories if a pattern is in one directory but not the other directory, copy it to a third directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have

```
dir_1=/foo
dir_2=/foo/bar
file_unique=/foo/bar/tmp/
```

Compare two directories `dir_1` and `dir_2`. I want to look for files matching a pattern in `dir_1` and `dir_2` called `*.PATTERN`.

`PATTERN` is a placeholder for any word. `dir_1` file examples are `lockinfo.1234.mikey` or `lockinfo.1235.mikey`. `dir_2` file examples are `1234.mickey.AB` and `1235.mikey.AB`.

If the pattern exists in `dir_1` but not `dir_2` then copy complete file to the directory `file_unique`

Comment: Oh, as a general note, you don't look for patterns, you look for file(s) matching a pattern. It's probably what you meant, but it's different

Comment: Is `PATTERN` intended to be a literal word, or is it supposed to represent something? Please provide examples of a file that might be in both `dir_1` and `dir_2`, as well as another example of a file that's in `dir_1` but not in `dir_2`. Using these examples, explain what `*.PATTERN` is supposed to match. [Edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/749307/edit) to add this information as if you'd provided it originally - don't respond here in the comments

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? This is just to get you started, it isn't very robust....

```
dir_1=<some directory, e.g., /foo>
dir_2=<some directory, e.g., /foo/bar>
file_unique=<some directory, e.g., /foo/bar/tmp/>
for file in ${dir_1}/lockinfo.*.PATTERN; do
   # first, are there any matching files? If not, $file will
   # be set literally to ".../lockinfo.*.PATTERN"
   [[ ! -f "$file"]] && break
   # OK, there is at least one file
   basename=$(basename ${file})
   # if there is no such file in dir_2, cp the original
   # file, preserving its permissions and ownership, etc.
   [[ ! -f ${dir_2}/${basename} ]] && cp -p $file $file_unique
done
```

Add additional error checking, support for spaces, etc., as required.

Comment: Double quote the variables when you use them, e.g. `for file in "${dir_1}"/lockinfo.*.PATTERN`, assuming that `lockinfo.*.PATTERN` is intended to be a glob. And `[ ! -f "$dir_2/$basename" ]`

Comment: `basename=$(basename ${file})` can be more efficiently written `basename=${file##*/}`

Comment: If you change your use of `[[ … ]]` to `[ … ]` you'll have a POSIX script too, not just one that requires `bash` to run