# I want to look for files matching a pattern in dir_1 and dir_2 called *.PATTERN and copy to another directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have

```
dir_1=/foo
dir_2=/foo/bar
file_unique=/foo/bar/tmp/
```

Compare two directories `dir_1` and `dir_2`. I want to look for files matching a pattern in `dir_1` and `dir_2` called `*.PATTERN`

PATTERN is a placeholder for any word. `dir_1` file examples are `lockinfo.1234.mikey` or `lockinfo.1235.mikey`.

`dir_2 file` examples are `1234.mickey.AB` and `1235.mikey.AB`

If the pattern exists in `dir_1` but not `dir_2` then copy complete file to the directory `file_unique`

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup folders for our different stages
dir_1=/dev/shm
dir_2=/var/spool/jobs
file_unique=/dev/shm/tmp

mkdir /dev/shm/tmp

for file in "${dir_1}"/.lockinfo.*.mickey; do
     [[ ! -f "$file"]]  &&  break   
      basename=$(basename ${file})
      [[ ! -f ${dir_2}/${basename} ]] && cp -p $file $file_unique
done
```

The above gives errors:

```
gpu_lock_healthcheck.ver1: line 13: unexpected token `newline', conditional binary operator expected

gpu_lock_healthcheck.ver1: line 13: syntax error near `break'

gpu_lock_healthcheck.ver1: line 13: `         [[ ! -f "$file"]]  &&  break   '
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using bash, compare two directories if a pattern is in one directory but not the other directory, copy it to a third directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749307/using-bash-compare-two-directories-if-a-pattern-is-in-one-directory-but-not-the)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line 13: There must be a space before the closing `]]` (after `"$file"`) so that the shell recognizes it as the end of the conditional test construct.

I would recommend that you check shell scripts with the [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net) tool, also available standalone on many Linux distributions, to detect such errors.